# What is the best method for creating a static class that uses threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-3.5

Let's say I am designing a simple logging class (yes - I **know** there are those already out there in the wild!) and I want the class to be static so the rest of my code can call it without having to instantiate it first.  Maybe something like this:

```
internal static class Log
{
    private static string _logFile = "";

    internal static void InitializeLogFile(string path)
    {
        ...
    }
    internal static void WriteHeader()
    {
        ...
    }
    internal static void WriteLine(params string[] items)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, I want the internals to spin up their own thread and execute in an Asynch manner, possibly using BackgroundWorker to help simplify things.  Should I just create a new BackgroundWorker in each method, create a static BackgroundWorker as a private property of the static class, or is there something I am overlooking altogether?

Comment: You'd be much better off with a non-static class and a single static (singleton) instance of it in your application.  Static classes are necessary for extension methods but otherwise best avoided.

Comment: Isn't `BackgroundWorker` supposed to be used in WinForms?

Comment: @bzlm BackgroundWorker is applicable across .NET; not just WinForms

Comment: @Aaron, @bzlm: Though BackgroundWorker _can_ work anywhere in a .NET app, it's not ideal and wasn't intended to. ThreadPool is preferred in that kind of scenario.

Comment: @SnOrfus While BackgroundWorker did surface in .NET 2 and WinForms was the focus there is no reason not to continue to use the BackgroundWorker for certain situations...it is not an either or, they can co-exist for specific tasks. The BackgroundWorker is pulling from the ThreadPool anyways and provides a nice way to push feedback to the UI under certain scenarios.

Comment: Just what the world needs, yet another log class ;)

Comment: All of these are good answers - and goes to show how many ways a single problem can be solved.  Don't get hung up on the "logger" part as that was the first thought I had to demonstrate the problem space I am trying to resolve with our system.  Yes, I have to write files asynch.  No, they are not logging files, they end up being consumed elsewhere by other apps.  (And I was thinking of calling it **Lincoln.Logs** so I could build on it later.  lol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good call,

You definitely want the logging operations to occur in a separate thread as the code that is doing the logging. For instance, the accessor methods (such as "logEvent(myEvent)" ) should not block on file I/O operations while the logger logs the event to a file.

Make a queue so that the accessors simply push items onto the queue. This way your code shouldn't block while it is trying to log an event.

Start-up a second thread to empty the internal queue of events. This thread can run on a static private method of your logger class.

The performance drawback comes when you try to ensure thread safety of the underlying event queue. You will need to acquire a lock on the queue every time before a pop or push onto the queue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I selected this approach and have it working for us now.  I do like using the Queue objects.  I do want to note that all of the answers here are very good!

Answer (score 2):

You definitely do not want spin up a new thread or `BackgroundWorker` on each invocation of the methods. I would use the producer-consumer pattern here. As it turns out this is such a common pattern that Microsoft provided us with the `BlockingCollection` class which simplies the implementation greatly. The nice thing about this approach is that:

- there is only one extra thread required
- the `Log` methods will have asynchronous semantics
- the temporal ordering of the log messages is preserved

Here is some code to get your started.

```
internal static class Log
{
  private static BlockingCollection<string> s_Queue = new BlockingCollection<string>();

  static Log()
  {
    var thread = new Thread(Run);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
  }

  private static void Run()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      string line = s_Queue.Take();
      // Add code to append the line to the log here.
    }
  }

  internal static void WriteLine(params string[] items)
  {
    foreach (string item in items)
    {
      s_Queue.Add(item);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not finding this in .NET 3.5 - looks to be an addition to the 4.0 framework.

Comment: It is also available via the Reactive Extensions download which is a port of the TPL for framwork 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

You only want to have 1 thread per log file/db.  Otherwise, the order of items in the log is unreliable.  Have a background thread that pulls from a thread-safe queue and does the writing.

Comment: Ran into this with the idea that I posted. Forgot to mention that. For me, the order was "good enough". Order was only not maintained within a time slice. A time slice for me was at worse 100ms. If two thing happened within 100ms of each other, it didn't matter much to me. If timing was important, I just added a time stamp and/or which thread to the output. but good point to bring up  :-)

Comment: I guarantee that several months from know when you are debugging some complex issue this will come back to bite you and you'll spend hours distracted from debugging an issue by trying to figure out why things are happening in the wrong order... and then just after you've given up and started driving home you'll remember "oh man, I should have listened to that Robert guy on StackOverflow and used a single thread for logging".  Guaranteed.

Comment: Also, if you have multiple threads trying writing to the same file, at the same time bad things will happen... depending on how you open the file, either an exception will be thrown or log entries will be lost/overwritten.   And it will be difficult to debug this when the issue gets encountered later... no reason not to do it right the first time.  Lastly, creating a lot of short lived and threads is a very poor use of CPU resources.  There's a good chance that this will actually slow down your app instead of speed it up if you are writing frequently to the log.

Comment: The threads don't write to the file, they write to their own queue. The thread for the object itself handles writing to the file and that's single threaded. Anyway, order is maintained with a given thread. Debugging info lists which thread and a time stamp for a given line. Your points are probably very good and important for other people, but for my one particular project it doesn't matter. Thanks for the tips though :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that my recommendation is not exactly what you expect, but I hope it is useful anyway:

- Don't use a static class. Instead,
  use a regular class and hold a single
  instance of it (the [singleton
  pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)); using a dependency
  injection engine helps a lot with
  this (I use [MS Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff663144.aspx) and it
  works fine). If you define an interface for your logging class as well, your code will be much more testable.
- As for the threading stuff, if I
  understand correclty you want the
  logging work to be performed in
  separate threads. Are you sure that
  you really need this? A logger should
  be light enough so that you can
  simple call the "Write" methods and
  expect that your application
  performance will not suffer.

A last note: you mention the BackgroundWorker class, but if I am not wrong this class is intended for use with desktop applications, not with ASP.NET. In this environment you should probably use something like [the ThreadPool class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=VS.90).aspx).

Just my 2 euro cents...

Comment: BackgroundWorker can be used within ASP.NET

Comment: I didn't say it couldn't be used. But I think it is not *intended* for it. It is good to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I created a thread safe logging class myself a while back. I used it something like this.

```
Logging obj = new Logging(filename);
Action<string> log = obj.RequestLog();
```

RequestLog would return an anonymous method that wrote to its own Queue. Because a Q is thread safe for 1 reader/writer, I didn't need to use any locks when calling log()

The actual Logging object would create a new thread that ran in the background and would periodically check all of the queues. If a Q had a string in it, it would write it to a buffered file stream.

I added a little extra code to the reading thread so for each pass it made on the queues, if there was nothing written, it would sleep an extra 10 ms, up to a max of 100ms. This way the thread didn't spool too much. But if there was heavy writing going on, it would poll the Qs every 10ms.

Here's a snpit of the return code for the requested queue. The "this.blNewData = true" was so I didn't need to hit up every Q to see if any new data was written. No lock involved because a false positive still did no work since all the Qs would be empty anyway.

OutputQueue was the list of Queues that I looped through to see if anything was written. The code to loop through the list was in a lock in case NewQueueLog() was called and caused the list to get resized.

```
public Action<String> NewQueueLog()
{
    Queue<String> tmpQueue = new Queue<String>(32);
    lock (OutputQueue)
    {
        OutputQueue.Add(tmpQueue);
    }
    return (String Output) =>
    {
        tmpQueue.Enqueue(Output);
        this.blNewData = true;
    };
}
```

In the end, writing to the log was lock free, which helped when lots of threads were writing.